# Two-sample test for multivariate normal distributions under the assumption that means are the same

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

Let $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be a sample from a multivariate Gaussian distribution ${\cal N}(0, \Sigma_X)$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^m$ be a sample from ${\cal N}(0, \Sigma_Y)$.

Are there hypothesis tests for $\Sigma_X = \Sigma_Y$? Pointers to relevant literature would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Mauchly's test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauchly%27s_sphericity_test) allows to test if a given covariance matrix is proportional to a reference (identity or other) and is available through `mauchly.test()` under R. It is mostly used in repeated-measures design (to test (1) if the dependent variable VC matrices are equal or homogeneous, and (2) whether the correlations between the levels of the within-subjects variable are comparable--altogether, this is known as the *sphericity assumption*).

Box’s M statistic is used (in MANOVA or LDA) to test for homogeneity of covariance matrices, but as it is very sensitive to normality it will often reject the null ([R code](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/Rhelp02a/archive/33330.html) not available in standard packages).

Covariance structure models as found in [Structural Equation Modeling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_equation_modeling) are also an option for more complex stuff (although in multigroup analysis testing for the equality of covariances makes little sense if the variances are not equal), but I have no references to offer actually.

I guess any textbook on multivariate data analysis would have additional details on these procedures. I also found this article for the case where normality assumption is not met:

> Aslam, S and Rocke, DM. [A robust
>   testing procedure for the equality of
>   covariance matrices](http://dmrocke.ucdavis.edu/papers/Aslam.Rocke.2005.pdf), Computational
>   Statistics & Data Analysis 49 (2005)
>   863-874